# WPF user control with sub-panel that accepts other controls at design time

Tags: .net, wpf, user-controls, design-time

How do I create a WPF user control with a sub-panel that accepts other controls at design time? I'm trying to write a user control with a toolbar at the top and a panel beneath for "dynamic content", to add  to the toolbox for other devlopers to use.

I've done this is Winforms before, but I've not been able to figure it out for WPF.

EDIT:
Or am I going at this completely wrong, stuck in Winforms-thinking? I mean, what I want is for users to not having to add the toolbar everytime. Should I instead inherit from, I don't know, `StackPanel` and make sure the toolbar alwasys is the upper most control, and have developers add their stuff beneath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would [write a custom control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295235.aspx) (not a user control) by deriving from [ContentControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.aspx). The toolbar at the top would come from the [ControlTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.controltemplate.aspx) that you will have to write for your control. Additionally somewhere in your ControlTemplate you would define a [ContentPresenter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentpresenter.aspx) (or alternatively another control with `SomeProperty="{TemplateBinding Content}"`). That will be the place where the content (i.e. the UIElement that the user of your control added as a child to an instance of your control) will be displayed.

Comment: Ok. This gets me about as far as I got when using User Control, but I still don't get how to open up an area for additional controls. How do I create the sub-panel that accepts other controls at design time?

Comment: A bit cryptic, but this did help me alot in figuring out what to do. :)